# HTML5 Canvas - drawing fails once shifting the current browser tab

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Ok, I've noticed this bug happen not only in the following code(which is just to illustrate), but every code I've written for canvas;
basically, in chrome(I didn't test other browsers),
 once you shift your current tab to either a different pc screen, or simply if you have a few tabs in a row and decide to make a new window out of your current tab, 
the canvas itself fails to draw. it is stuck and no reason is given in the console.

Here is a GIF of it happening:

http://gifmaker.cc/PlayGIFAnimation.php?folder=2016081601ZEuvXaZnxC2T9fHNNqSW3l&file=output_f72O1H.gif

Just a simple canvas code if you want to try it out:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
<script>


// grab the canvas and context
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// inital coordinates of the black square
var x = 0;
var y = 200;

// speed of the movement in x- and y-direction
// actual no movement in y-direction
var vX = 1;
var vY = 0;

// width and height of the square
var width = 10;
var height = 10;

function animate() {
    // clear
    // comment this clear function to see the plot of the sine movement
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);    

    x += vX;
    y += vY;

    // if the block leaves the canvas on the right side
    // bring it back to the left side
    if(x>500) {
        x = 0;
    }

    ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

    setTimeout(animate, 33);
}
// call the animate function manually for the first time
animate();
</script>
```

Some sites fixed this bug but I don't know if I am allowed to link them here.

Comment: to understand your issue is when browser display the canvas it's empty but if you drag it in a new tab you can see the canvas content ?

Comment: No, the contrary; once you drag the tab and turn it into a new window, the canvas content disappear.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this issue with Chrome or Firefox. Maybe try replacing setTimeout with requestAnimationFrame?

Comment: Sorry, requestAnimationFrame didn't help